Visual Studio / Git Changes / Pop and Apply stashes does not clear the stashes
When I use the options to Pop and Apply stashed changes, the stashes remain in the Stashes menu.
Pop and Apply is supposed to a) Pop the stash and b), apply it.  And once it is popped, it should not show under stashes.
I did use the option to include any staged files.
With all my changes applied here is what I see:

If my understanding is right, there should be no entries under Stashes -- Pop and Apply should have cleared all Stashes, right?

If there is a conflict when applying the stash, the stash is not dropped by Git. That could be a reason.

makes sense, there were some.  They were fixed.  So now it's all just manual -- make sure the changes are applied and then just manually drop them.  The bad thing is the changes will get re-applied if Apply or Pop are used again.  Then the site crashes due to duplicate variables, etc.  So it's not perfect.  I'll just manually clear these.

You will be way better of by stopping using stash at all and instead just use temporary commits.

git stash pop removes a stash entry when there's no conflict while git stash apply always does not. It depends on what's behind the option and if there is any conflict.
